# IIS File Size Reporting

Tags: iis

How do I configure IIS to report File Size for browser downloads. As it stands now, all downloads off our site report a null file size, and therefor do not show file size progress.

We're using version 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to log sc-bytes (sc=server to client) in W3C Extended Log Format.  This is the total bytes in the HTTP response header and response data (ie- file).  cs-bytes (client to server) is the amount of data sent in the request from the client and not indicative of browser downloads.  This will be the total bytes of the http header plus any post data that is sent with the request.

If you're using Microsoft IIS Log Format you want to look at the Server Bytes sent field.  In NCSA common log file format you want to look at Bytes Sent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean in the IIS logs. If you're using W3C Extended Log File Format for your logs you can select several parameters on the Advanced tab of the logging properties. The two you probably want to enable are bytes sent (server to client) and bytes received (client to server).